# Increase variable by amount per second - Swift Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

Simple question here while coding in swift. How to I increase a variable by a certain amount per second?

I am trying to increase a y value of a CGPoint 258 points per second. I was thinking of making a function that would repeat itself that many times per second and increase a variable, but is this the wrong approach?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Setup a `NSTimer` which fires once a second and add 258 to your variable in the timer function.

Comment: Great! Do you know some code that could help me out? Now I know what to do, but I don't know how to code that line. Thanks so much

Comment: I have put an example in the answer

Comment: I think you should explain why you need to do this? If you are trying to move something, such as a view, then the built in animation methods, or maybe even UIKit Dynamics, are a far better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a `NSTimer` in your class and add 258 to your variable in the timer function. Here is an example for a `UIViewController` class:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: NSTimer?
    var myVariable: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        // fired once a second
        myVariable += 258
    }
}
```

Comment: This will just keep increasing until you stop it.

Comment: It's not what I asked for. Also, it's sometimes a better idea to answer the real question rather than just providing exactly what is being asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realize that I might have not explained very clearly what I am trying to achieve. Here it is:  I need to increase the y value of a CGPoint 258 points per second. I am drawing a line on the view that takes the touchesBegan xy value and draws a line to the touchesMoved updating xy value. This works so far, but I need to have the y value of the touchesBegan to increase by 258 points per second so the line will be redrawn showing the touchesBegan point moving but tM folow finger. Make sense??? Really hard to explain. I really appreciate the help that has been given though

Comment: Anybody have any more ideas?